# IPA file should be visible on the build server. but cant find .ipa file on mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ipa

i am trying to genrate .ipa file for my xamarin application.
its get genrated with this message

> IPA file should be visible on the build server

sometimes popup automatically opens on my mac machine where .ipa file gets generated.

but most of times it doesn't .then where can i find  that .ipa file on my mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check bin folder in IOS project

Answer (score 1):

Please select iPhone instead of iPhoneSimulator in build configuration